# google play game service errors

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to try google play game service in my own app, I download the sample from web and have a try with it. But when I run the sample, here are some errors show in my log cat.

Unable to retrieve 1p application 336969378003
Unable to load player 102010880864480302016

I hava set up the app correctly on the console and I don't know what's wrong with it. Waiting for your answer. Thx for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

In [Step 3. Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id) it specifically gives a warning as follows:

```
Warning: 
Do not open the Google APIs Console directly and manually add 
your Client IDs on that page. Doing so might cause errors 
when you send requests to the game services.
```

So my experience was that you need to follow the guide religiously: [Setting Up Google Play Game Services with the Google Play Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling)

Answer (score 0):

As Sachin Chavan said, follow the guide to the letter. You need to use the Google Play Developer Console, not the API console. Also:

1. (Easy to miss) If the app is not yet published, check that you are added to the app's list of testers. To do that, go to the Google Play Developer Console, find your app, go to the "Testing" tab, add yourself to the list.
2. When you created your client ID, you are asked for a package name and a certificate fingerprint (SHA1). Check carefully that the package name on the client ID matches the package name of your app; check carefully that the certificate you are signing your app with matches the fingerprint you placed on the client ID.