# Can't go to Google Play Services Leaderboards. Error: Unable to load player

Tags: android, google-play-services

I created Google leaderboards services in the tested mode everything was working but now that is in live mode I can't connect to leaderboards.

In my logcat I get the error (Unable to load player ......):

```
09-07 12:31:32.013 994-3897/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11411000, Services 11055034, and Games 52250034
09-07 12:31:32.013 994-3864/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11411000, Services 11055034, and Games 52250034
09-07 12:31:32.044 11766-11766/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 6 to 7
09-07 12:31:32.060 994-1141/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11411000, Services 11055034, and Games 52250034
09-07 12:31:32.091 11766-11766/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 7 to 8
09-07 12:31:32.106 994-3864/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 11411000, Services 11055034, and Games 52250034
09-07 12:31:32.169 745-1918/? I/GCM.HTTP: Last HTTP status code for blocked entry: 500
09-07 12:31:32.169 745-1918/? W/GCM.HTTP: HTTP request blocked due to automatic backoff: https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US
09-07 12:31:32.169 994-1652/? W/GoogleURLConnFactory: Blocked by temporary_blocked2: https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US
09-07 12:31:32.169 994-12949/? E/PlayerAgent: Unable to load player g03107294930939934924
09-07 12:31:32.169 11766-11766/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 8 to 11
09-07 12:31:32.169 11766-11766/? W/SignInActivity: onSignInFailed()...
09-07 12:31:32.169 11766-11766/? W/SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 8
09-07 12:31:32.169 11766-11766/? W/SignInActivity: ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
09-07 12:31:32.216 146-146/? I/Crayon_Player: ==> seekTo(7733)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Kindly double check the [Step 3. Generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id) and specifically follow the step on generating  an OAuth 2.0 client ID for your game. Also as stated in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792170/5995040), religiously follow the guide : [Setting Up Google Play Game Services with the Google Play Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling). Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I somehow go to the Google Play services I enter wrong SHA fingerprint. But now I get error: Attempting to access a resource for another application. Check your resource IDs.  and Attempt to access application 1085975891602 from application 979171240652.   But I dont know why because I have in my strings xml app id: 1085975891602